# Make keyboard shortcut inactive when text input is focused

Tags: visual-studio-code, key-bindings

I'd like to set a keyboard shortcut for creating a new file to just "n" when a file tree is visible. I added a new keyboard shortcut for `explorer.newFile` and set the when clause to `filesExplorerFocus && !treeFindOpen` (the second term is to disable the shortcut when I search inside the explorer with `CTRL + F`).

The problem is that now I can't use letter "n" to name the file, because this retriggers the shortcut. I know, that I should add just another "when" clause, but I can't figure out what is it.

Do you know which clause is responsible for state when "text input is active in the file explorer" or any similar state that could solve my issue. Or maybe you know a more generic way to find out what I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

```json
{
  "key": "n",
  "command": "explorer.newFile",
  "when": "filesExplorerFocus && !treeFindOpen && !inputFocus"
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried `textInputFocused` and it didn't work, so I thought I explored all of the options.